# How to copy filtered row?

Tags: google-apps-script

Using Google Apps Script for Google Sheet, this formula works to copy and paste visible row 77 :

```
function copyRow77() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var lRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
var lCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
var range = sheet.getRange(77,1,1, lCol);
sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 1, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});
}
}
```

But when row 77 is filtered, it doesn't work anymore...
Maybe an idea ?

Comment: Use `getValue()` and `setValue()`

Comment: The `getValue()` technique doesn't copy/paste values AND formulas. Furthermore the `getFormulas()` technique copy exact formulas without adapting datas to the new rows/columns numbers...

Comment: You can use `getFormulasR1C1`, that will adapt to other rows/columns when copied. You can start at that. This is in no way an answer to your question, but to your comment where `getFormulas` wont adapt to new rows/columns

Comment: Would you be able to share a sample sheet with sanitized data so that we can try and replicate?

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: Then just remove the filter and reapply it after copy pasting. [Edit] your question with formulas/data structure and other issues.

Comment: Fantastic ! It works with `getFormulasR1C1()` and `setFormulas()' ! Thank you AsyntuBU :)

Comment: If the question is already answered, I'd suggest posting it as an answer so that the community will be able to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

**As AsyntuBU stated:**

You can use getFormulasR1C1, that will adapt to other rows/columns when copied. You can start at that. This is in no way an answer to your question, but to your comment where getFormulas wont adapt to new rows/columns